# Why is my prime number calculator not working?

Tags: javascript, calculator

Here is my code.  It would really help me if someone could tell me what is wrong. And performance tips are also highly appreciated.

btw the html is just a button onclick prime().

```
function prime() {
  var teller = 1;
  var n = document.getElementById("a").value;
    document.write("2, ");
  checkPrime(n, 1);    
}

function checkPrime(n, teller) {
  if(isPrime(teller)) {
    document.write(teller + ", ");
  }
  if(teller < n) {
    checkPrime(n, teller = teller + 2);
  }
}

function isPrime(n) {
  var isPrime = true;
  if (n < 2 || n != Math.round(n) ) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      isPrime = false;
    }
  }
  return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: What are you experiencing that is making it `wrong`?

Comment: i'm trying to show all the prime numbers up to the number the user inputs.

Comment: But it stops at +- 60.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for checking with modulus seems correct but the teller variable seemed strange to me. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44e7xyw7/4/) and your code without the teller var.

```
 function prime() {
    var teller = 1;
    var n = document.getElementById("a").value;
    checkPrime(n);

}

function checkPrime(n) {
    var primes = isPrime(n);
    if (primes) alert(primes.length + " primes found : " + primes.join())
    else alert("Error");
}

function isPrime(n) {
    var isPrime = true;
    var primeArray = new Array();
    if (n <= 2 || n != Math.round(n)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var j = 3; j <= n; j++) {
        var primeFound = true;
        for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(j); i++) {
            if (j % i == 0) {
                primeFound = false;
            }
        }
        if (primeFound) primeArray.push(j);
    }

    return primeArray;
}
```

This **isn't the most efficient** code though. It would be faster to check by only the primes already found instead of trying to divide by all the integers up to sqrt(j).

Comment: thx but i should have been more specific. See i'm trying to show all the prime numbers up to the number the user inputs.